# If $a|b$ and $b>0$, then $a \leq b$.

Tags: solution-verification, divisibility

Proof:

If $a | b $ then $b = an$  with $n \in \mathbb Z$ and $b > 0$.
Suppose that $a \geq b$.

if $b =1 \Longrightarrow 1 =an \Longrightarrow a = \frac{1}{n}$.

if $n < 0$ then $a = \frac{1}{-n}$ and if $n > 0$ then $a = \frac{1}{n}$. contradicts that $a \geq b$  !

therefore, $a \leq b$.

I want to know if my proof is correct.

Comment: You've proven that $a \mid b \implies a \geq b$ when $b = 1$. What about when $b \neq 1$? You've also introduced a proof by contradiction for no reason (notice that you never use $a \geq b$ in your proof). Step back and try to write a more direct proof.

Comment: Note that even if you insist on contradiction, $a \geq b$ is not the negation of $a \leq b$.

Comment: To add to my comment, notice that the only non-trivial fact here is that $b = an \geq a$ when $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ and $a > 0$. The rest is case management (What if $a = 0$? What if $a < 0$?). I say "non-trivial," but hopefully with it broken down like this you see that there really isn't much to prove.

Comment: I suppose you're looking for a rigorous proof instead of a more intuitive/visual one?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins I tried with your second comment and I didn't use contradiction. Thanks. With $a< 0$ and $a =0$ it is not possible when $b > 0$.

Comment: @Arkyter Yes, a rigorous proof.

Comment: @jrussell Yes, $a = 0$ is not possible. $a < 0$ is possible, but quickly reduces to a case we've already dealt with upon realizing that $-a > 0$.

Comment: If $a>b$ then write $a=b+y$ for some $y>0$. Then $an=b=(b+y)n$, so...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove this by assuming that $b=1$. You need to prove this for a *generic* $b>0$.

It's simpler: if $a\le0$, then clearly $a\le b$. So we can assume $a>0$ and that $b=an$, with $n>0$. In particular $n\ge1$ and so $an\ge a$.

If you want to do it by contradiction, you need to assume $a>b$ (which is the correct negation of $a\le b$). Then $a>0$ and from $b=an$ we deduce that $n>0$ as well. Now we have $a>b=an$, so $a>an$, which implies $1>n$, which is a contradiction.